# Recovery crypt password

Tags: encryption

I remove crypt password using "sudo cryptsetup luksRemoveKey /dev/sda5". Now after restarting it is asking for crypt password again, and it is not accepting the old password. Now I have no idea about it, I don't know what to do now. Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

From the `man cryptsetup`:

> WARNING: If you read the passphrase from stdin (without  further argument  or  with '-' as an argument to --key-file), batch-mode (-q) will be implicitly switched on and no warning will be given when  you  remove the last remaining passphrase from a LUKS container. Removing the last passphrase makes  the  LUKS  container permanently inaccessible.

If you have removed the last passphrase, it is **unrecoverable**. You will have to restore from backup. Commonly you only have one passphrase configured, unless you have manually at some stage added more keys.

You can verify if you have any remaining keys in use with `sudo cryptsetup luksDump /dev/sda5`.

If it comes up with no slots in use, then sorry, data is gone.